# Is it possible to run two, seperate operating systems on a computer?

Tags: operating-system

I imagine this would be accomplished by assigning some RAM and L3 cache to one OS, some to another, and having two hard drives and two monitors. I don't know if its possible to do that at all, and if it is, how? A wrapper OS? Are there any functional examples?

I know that most advantages of such a system can be acquired by virtualization, but that is different than what I mean.

Comment: What about virtualization?

Comment: Its definitely an option, but I'm wondering if its possible to truly have them side-by-side, instead of one wrapped up in another.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible. It would mean that two OS can share the same physical processor, manage its computation order etc.

Comment: Thats why I was thinking of a wrapper OS. it would be able to divide the shared cache, and the unshared cache isnt an issue anyway. But then it would process everything natively for both true OS's

Comment: I don't think it could be possible. Take a look to this to know more: http://superuser.com/questions/333297/is-it-possible-to-dual-boot-two-oss-at-the-same-time

Comment: Thank you very much. in that post, I found what I was describing: a bare-metal hypervisor. I dont think theres a way to mark that as an answer, so if you make it an answer, I'll check it off.

Comment: well Actually It is possible. I'll post my complete answer in couple of hours

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically It is possible to have multiple operating system running on a single machine but on different cores. Like one core will be running windows and other will be running linux distro. Though It is very hard to achieve, because both OS assume that It is the only king of the island, and tries to rule on everything like memory and devices. Eventually without having any exclusive lock, both OS will confuse hardware or itself and crash.
Let's come to the point that **How is it even possible theoretically?**
 This is possible through asymmetric multiprocessing (AMP), Before executing operating system A you hide the 2nd core so that OS will assume that there is only one core present on the machine then after OS will setup environment for that core.
Once things are ready this side, You ask operating system B to load up on 2nd core by hiding first core. And yes you need a separate program except boot loader to do all of this work.
Now you have two OS running but what about memory? devices? Yes that's a major concern. One workaround that I could see is to modify kernel of OS A and OS B such that you could properly divide system resources. Like you tell the OS A to use lower 2GB memory to use and assume upper 2GB as not available, thus modify OS B to use upper 2GB memory.
Memory concern is resolved, but than It would little tricky to modify every device driver to do that.

I guess this is the only reason for not doing such kind of experiment. It isn't worthy at all.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of virtualization, it would really not be possible to do this on any current processors.

When the processor receives an interrupt, what operating system handles it?